# Use Selenium to extract span text content

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web

can't figure out how to use selenium in python script to extract span text content: **RSB - 12498** from the html shown. Please help. Thanks.

`<div _ngcontent-pfw-c3="" class="strip_list wow fadeIn animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeIn;"><figure _ngcontent-pfw-c3=""><a _ngcontent-pfw-c3="" href="detail-page.html"><img _ngcontent-pfw-c3="" alt="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/565x565.jpg"></a></figure><small _ngcontent-pfw-c3=""><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-pfw-c3=""> RSB - 12498</span>`

Comment: can you share a link to the page where this element exists?

Comment: In order to locate this element uniquely and correctly we need to see the entire page HTML

Comment: @Prophet  https://search.cac.gov.ng/list . I'm trying to scrape from a random search

Comment: I don't see `RSB - 12498` or even `12498` there

Comment: Or maybe I need to search there somehow ?

Comment: I tried some search, entered "new york" and got several results..

Comment: @Prophet okay cool. just need to get that RC number at the top. It's a span text. "RC *******"

Comment: @Prophet for every search result there is an RC number, that's what I want to scrape

Comment: Why not just post `{"searchTerm":"12498"}` to `https://searchapp.cac.gov.ng/searchapp/api/public-search/company-business-name-it` Response is `{"status":"OK","success":true,"errorCode":0,"data":[{"state":null,"id":177965,"address":"27,GBOLADESTR,,LAGOS,LAGOS",..."approvedName":"MISLAD NIG LTD","rcNumber":"12498",...{"state":null,"id":678722,"address":"1STFLOOR,RUBYBLOCK,ALLSEASONSPLAZA,AGIDINGIKEJALAGOS,IKEJA,LAGOS","status":"ACTIVE","city":null,"email":null,"approvedName":"EARTHWATCH FOUNDATION","rcNumber":"12498",....`

Comment: @greg616 did my answer resolved your problem?

Comment: @Prophet error message: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//small/span"}

Comment: @greg616 Maybe you are missing some wait? Just try putting a delay after clicking the search button before accessing the results

Comment: Or try using css selector instead

Comment: @Prophet yes I did that. Don't know why I'm getting same error. Thanks though. Will troubleshoot. It did return the result for you?

Comment: Sure, I see them clearly on dev tools

Comment: Great, you are welcome!

Comment: @Prophet pls I'm curious why I was getting errors in VS code terminal but got results when I used jupyter notebook

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't know. Don't hesitate to ask a new, separate question for this. I hope someone will be able to help you with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locator to locate such `span` element will be `//small/span` if you want to use XPath.
CSS selector will be `small span`
So Selenium command to get such single element text will be:

```py
goal = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('small span').text
print(goal)
```

Or

```py
goal = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//small/span').text
print(goal)
```

In case there are multiple search results, the texts can be received from the list of resulted elements:

```py
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('small span')
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

Or

```py
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//small/span')
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```